# How to enable a timer from a different thread/class

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

**Original post: [How to access a timer from another class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725413/how-to-access-a-timer-from-another-class-in-c)**

I tried everything.

-Event

-Invoke can't be done,because Timers don't have InvokeRequired property.

-Public/internal property

Nothing worked,the code is being executed,the timer.Enabled property is being set to "true" ,but it doesn't Tick.If I call the event or just change the property from the form class in a NON-static method - it does tick and works.

I never knew it would take me a day and probably more to acquire how to use a decent timer.

If there's no way to do this,is there anything else I can use that works similiar to the timer(delay,enable/disable)?

Comment: John, please add this to your previous question (You can edit your post), since this would be more helpful to other users having the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725413/how-to-access-a-timer-from-another-class-in-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the Timer class from the System.Timers namespace, and not the WinForms Timer control, if you want multi-threading support. Check the MSDN documentation for the WinForms Timer control for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Comment: While this will get the Elapsed event to fire (the System.Timer.Timer has an Elapsed event as opposed to the System.Windows.Forms.Timer's Tick event), it will be firing within the context of the calling thread and, depending upon what you do in the event, could result in a System.InvalidOperationException such as, "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'X' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Comment: Genius, I'd wasted a day on it. Never knew the quirk of windows forms timer.

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to check `InvokeRequired` on the Control iteself, you can check the property on the class e.g.:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired) 
{ 
    BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(delegate()
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I accidently tried to use invoke again,this time it worked,but I'll accept your answer,DavidM.

```
    public bool TimerEnable
    {
        set
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.timer.Enabled = value;
            });
        }
    }


    public static void timerEnable()
    {
        var form = Form.ActiveForm as Form1;
        if (form != null)
            form.TimerEnable = true;
    }
```

Comment: What if your timer is on another class? You wont be able to invoke with `this`. I think a scalable approach is by @David M

Answer (score 1):

Just because `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` doesn't have the ability to invoke, doesn't mean that your form doesn't. Try my `InvokeEx` from the second (or other) thread to enable the timer.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
  public static TResult InvokeEx<TControl, TResult>(this TControl control,
                            Func<TControl, TResult> func)
    where TControl : Control
  {
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
      return (TResult)control.Invoke(func, control);
    }
    else
    {
      return func(control);
    }
  }
}
```

With this, the following code worked for me:

```
new Thread(() =>
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    this.InvokeEx(f => f.timer1.Enabled = true);
  }).Start();
```

And the timer instantly sprung to life after the 1 second.