# C# start a timer from another thread

Tags: c#

I have a timer which is made by main thread and now if I need to start the timer from another thread how can I do this?

Solved:
Here is my code:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate();

if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(delegate()
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }));
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725735/how-to-enable-a-timer-from-a-different-thread-class  Here is the post that I copied the code

Comment: If you have no idea what the code does why are you trying to use it?

Comment: But at least I have to try what the code is trying to do

Comment: *"But C# seems can't Find the mydelegate class"* - Neither can I, I don't blame the poor compiler.  Are we to assume that your code is correct and the compiler is broken?  If not, go ahead and post a complete code sample.

Comment: You need a reference to your timer object in the thread you are working with.  If you have more than one thread this can be dangerous though.  Why don't you start the timer on the UI thread before starting the secondary thread?  Can you put the timer on the secondary thread?

Comment: At some condition, the timer will start by main thread and some condition it will start by another thread, so I can't fix the timer on a thread